# How to make a condition on multi-valued field in solr

Tags: solr, lucene, solr-query-syntax, solr-multy-valued-fields

My SOLR is used to store events.
Events can repeat.
I need to filter my query to fetch events in a certain date range.

Data for example:
Event A has repeats in the following  dates 1st, 10th, 15th, 29th
Event B has repeats in the following  dates 2nd, 11th, 14th, 19th
Event C has repeats in the following  dates 4th and 25th.

I want all event that occur in between the 7th and 12th **Result**: event A and event B
Lets assume the field name is `multivalued=true`
Its type is

```
<fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
```

How would the url/query look like?

Comment: Thanks-that is what I figured. Migth as well put is as an answer and I'll accept it. This is a search system, and just one of the various filters on the search result is what is above. The most important one though is a keyword search, -> SOLR/Lucene

Comment: Moved the comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say Lucene index is really not the tool to use for this kind of task, but if there is some reason you must use it, I'd suggest making a distinct document for every pair (event, date) instead of multivalued fields. Then you won't have a problem formulating a query.